# how to assign a string containing multiple variable to char array?

Tags: c

Is it possible to assign a string wirth multiple variable to a char array ?

### For example :

```
char array[100];
int valeur=5;
int score=10;
array=("Bravo vous avez gagné %d points (total: %d)",valeur,score);
printf("%s\n",array);
```

- output :
  **Bravo vous avez gagné 5 points (total: 10)**

Comment: are you looking for `sprintf`?

Comment: `array` has only 10 chars, so the best you could put in it is "Bravo vou", You either need need a 2D array, or you need to make `array` large enough to hold the entire content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use sprintf(array, "Bravo vous avez gagne le yoyo et %d points", valeur);
You can add any variables like in printf.
sprintf(array, "Bravo vous avez gagne %d points et le score est %d", valeur, score);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` to write formatted output to a string (or better `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflows):

```
int main() {
    int valeur=5;
    int score=10;
    char array[100];
    snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "Bravo vous avez gagné %d points (total: %d)",valeur,score);
    printf("%s\n",array);

    //output :
    //Bravo vous avez gagné 5 points (total: 10)
}
```